# proper way to rename solution (and directories) under version control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, rename, projects-and-solutions, ankhsvn

I have a VS 2015 solution which is under version control with [AnkhSVN](https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

The solution name and one of the projects should be renamed, including the directories.

- What is the best way to do this, w/o causing issues with version
  control AnkhSVN?
- Any good tools available to accomplish this?

Comment: Subversion does not handle rename operation very well. Git and Mercurial should work better (though Git is still not quite intuitive).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with AnkhSVN, so I can not give a step-by-step guidance. However, you should be able to rename the solution and projects (on disk or in solution config) without issues when you use a Visual Studio plug-in such as AnkhSVN or VisualSVN.

However, you should follow a best practice that will help you prevent tree conflicts after the rename operation: do not perform the refactoring in branches. Perform rename operations and refactoring in trunk (mainline or master).